# jquery load function not working in internet explorer 9

Tags: jquery

I wanted to get alert once all the images gets load. This code is working in all browsers except ie

```
$('img').load(function(){    
  alert('hello')
});
```

not working in ie9. Any work around for this

Comment: Are you getting any console error? `.load()` works in IE9

Answer (score 0):

If your images that you are targeting are in the HTML of your document and this code is AFTER all the images in your document, then the images may have already finished loading before you can actually run this javascript:

```
$('img').load(function(){    
  alert('hello')
});
```

That means you can easily miss the `.load()` event because it will occur before you attach the event listener.  This is even more likely to happen if the image is in the browser cache.

What you can do is something like this:

```
<img src="xxx.jpg">
<img src="yyy.jpg">
<img src="zzz.jpg">

<script>
$('img').each(function() {
    if (this.complete) {
       // image already loaded (it finished before our javascript could run)
       console.log("image already loaded: " + this.src);
    } else {
        // it isn't loaded yet so set a load event handler to tell us when it does finish
        $(this).load(function() {
           console.log("image load event fired: " + this.src);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

---

If all you want to know is when all images in the HTML of the page have finished loading, you can use the `window.load` event:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    console.log("all images loaded now");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue most likely stems from this basic problem:

```
var i = new Image();
i.src = '/path/to/image'; // already cached by browser
i.onload = function() {
    alert('loaded!'); // will never get called
};
```

That said, the browser already has a mechanism to tell you when all images (and other external resources) have loaded:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert('hello'); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try using it in document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img').load(function(){    
     alert('hello')
   });
});
```

Comment: The main issue here is that some images may finish loading and thus fire their load events BEFORE you get to run this javascript.  Putting it inside of `$(document).ready()` does not help solve that issue.